# How can I iterate over a reversed range with a specific step in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iteration, range

I can iterate like this

```
(0..10).step(2){|v| puts v}
```

but, since reversed range is equal to empty range, I cannot iterate this way

```
(10..0).step(2){|v| puts v}
```

it will earn me nothing. Of course, I can iterate backward like this

```
10.downto(0){|v| puts v}
```

but downto method doesn't allow me to set other step except default 1. 
It's something very basic, so I suppose there should be a built-in way to do this, which i don't know.

Comment: you can do something like `(0..10).step(2).reverse` but you may need to add some logic in case the supposedly output from `(10..0).step(2)` is different.

Comment: `(0..10).step(2).reverse` isn't valid; Ruby says: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'reverse' for #<Enumerator: 0..10:step(2)>`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step):

From the docs:

> Invokes block with the sequence of numbers starting at num, incremented by step (default 1) on each call. The loop finishes when the value to be passed to the block is greater than limit (if step is positive) or less than limit (if step is negative). If all the arguments are integers, the loop operates using an integer counter. If any of the arguments are floating point numbers, all are converted to floats, and the loop is executed floor(n + n*epsilon)+ 1 times, where n = (limit - num)/step. Otherwise, the loop starts at num, uses either the < or > operator to compare the counter against limit, and increments itself using the + operator.

```
irb(main):001:0> 10.step(0, -2) { |i| puts i }
10
8
6
4
2
0
```

Comment: Nice. Also I found another way, less elegant though: (-10..0).step(2){|v| puts -1*v}

Answer (score 4):

it's very easy to emulate `step` by skipping values you don't need. Something like this:

```
10.downto(0).each_with_index do |x, idx|
  next if idx % 3 != 0 # every third element
  puts x
end
# >> 10
# >> 7
# >> 4
# >> 1
```

Comment: If you're conditionally skipping elements in an each statement you're doing it wrong, and should be using select: `10.downto(0).select.with_index { |x, idx| idx % 3 == 0 }.each { |x| puts x }`

Comment: @SamStephens: this is debatable.

Comment: Everything is, but I'll assert that if you're going to use the functional collection based features of Ruby, you should use them consistently, rather than mixing functional and imperative styles.

Comment: I personally don't see much functional code here. `each` is totally imperative. And `downto` generator is just a workaround.

Comment: I'd argue that what I've got across formatted across multiple lines is more readable once you're used to a functional approach to dealing with collection - you're clearly separating filtering and processing by separating the filtering of the select, and the processing of the each.

Comment: @SamStephens: I see what you mean. If we got the body of each from outside (block parameter or something), then separated filtering is certainly the way to go. In this case, they're equally fine, I'd say. There's the matter of performance too. In absense of lazy enumerators, my solution would be faster, I imagine. (this needs to be benchmarked, though)

Answer (score -1):

```
10.step(0, -2) do |v| puts "#{v}" end




10
8
6
4
2
0
```